# Install active directory after SP Farm installation

Tags: active-directory, installation, farm-setup

I have installed a SP2013 Farm everything works. Now for some reasons I need to install AD domain controller. 
Could this cause any problems to the FARM? 
What should I do before this operation to ensure functionality after?

Answer (score 1):

Never install SharePoint on a Domain Controler in Production environemnt as it is not supported. If it's DEV and you are trying to save resources, it will come with a cost: Workflow Development will not work, you'll loose lots of functions and there might be issues with services like User Profiles or Search. In other words it's not recommended.

Resources:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2012/07/26/sharepoint-2013-preview-stand-alone-server-set-up-facts-and-fallacies.aspx

https://briankgough.wordpress.com/2009/07/16/sharepoint-on-a-domain-controller/

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=204